# Apache tomcat not working with eclipse. Not able to start the server

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, server, tomcat8

I am having eclipse oxygen and tried to start my web application with Apache Tomcat 8, 8.5 and 9. I am still getting the below error. I am not sure is there any issue with java or eclipse level. Even i tried with many sub versions such as 8.5.11, 8.5.9, 8.0.53 etc.  Please help me.

The server not starting even without the application.

```
Jan 28, 2022 11:41:09 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:WebCSR-7.5.3.47' did not find a matching property.
Jan 28, 2022 11:41:09 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.0.53
Jan 28, 2022 11:41:09 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server built:          Jun 29 2018 14:42:45 UTC
Jan 28, 2022 11:41:09 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server number:         8.0.53.0
Jan 28, 2022 11:41:09 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Name:               Windows 10
Jan 28, 2022 11:41:09 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Version:            10.0
Jan 28, 2022 11:41:09 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Architecture:          amd64
Jan 28, 2022 11:41:09 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Java Home:             C:\FISWorkbench_Oxygen\FISWorkbench_Oxygen_ALPHA\jdk1.8.0_162\jre
Jan 28, 2022 11:41:09 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Version:           1.8.0_162-b12
Jan 28, 2022 11:41:09 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
Jan 28, 2022 11:41:09 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         C:\Backup\F Drive\D Drive\PROJECTS\CACF\CACF-2021\profile_workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
Jan 28, 2022 11:41:09 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         C:\software\apache-tomcat-8.0.53
Jan 28, 2022 11:41:09 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Backup\F Drive\D Drive\PROJECTS\CACF\CACF-2021\profile_workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
Jan 28, 2022 11:41:09 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\software\apache-tomcat-8.0.53
Jan 28, 2022 11:41:09 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=C:\Backup\F Drive\D Drive\PROJECTS\CACF\CACF-2021\profile_workspace\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps
Jan 28, 2022 11:41:09 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\software\apache-tomcat-8.0.53\endorsed
Jan 28, 2022 11:41:09 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252
Jan 28, 2022 11:41:09 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\FISWorkbench_Oxygen\FISWorkbench_Oxygen_ALPHA\jdk1.8.0_162\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\software\apache-ant-1.9.14-bin\apache-ant-1.9.14\bin;C:\app\e3005652\product\12.1.0\dbhome_1\bin;C:\app\e3005652\product\12.1.0\dbhome_2\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_301\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\software\apache-maven-3.6.1\bin;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Users\e3005652\Downloads\sonar-runner-2.4\bin;C:\Program Files\Git LFS;C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin;C:\software\apache-maven-3.6.1\bin;C:\Users\e3005652\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32;C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.2\bin;C:\Users\e3005652\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\Scripts;c:\users\e3005652\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages;C:\Derby\lib\*;C:\Program Files\Intel\WiFi\bin\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Intel\WirelessCommon\;C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Utilities 1.6\;C:\Users\e3005652\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Backup\F Drive\D Drive\PROJECTS\Innovate_48\xsltproc\pack;C:\Users\e3005652\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Scripts;C:\Program Files (x86)\openshift;C:\software\gradle-6.5.1-bin\gradle-6.5.1\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\1E\Client\Extensibility\NomadBranch;C:\Program Files\PuTTY\;C:\Program Files\WSO2\API Manager\3.2.0\bin\..\bin;C:\Program Files\WSO2\Enterprise Integrator\6.6.0\bin\..\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\dotnet\;C:\Users\e3005652\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\software\apache-maven-3.6.1\bin;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Users\e3005652\Downloads\sonar-runner-2.4\bin;C:\Users\e3005652\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32;C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.2\bin;C:\Backup\F Drive\D Drive\PROJECTS\WebLogic\Oracle\Middleware\wl122130\user_projects\domains\clean_domain\bin;C:\Derby\lib\*;C:\Users\e3005652\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_301\bin;;.
Jan 28, 2022 11:41:09 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8082"]
Jan 28, 2022 11:41:10 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Jan 28, 2022 11:41:10 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Jan 28, 2022 11:41:10 AM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Jan 28, 2022 11:41:10 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 1875 ms
Jan 28, 2022 11:41:10 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Jan 28, 2022 11:41:10 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.0.53
Jan 28, 2022 11:41:10 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:945)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:871)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1410)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1400)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:162)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/ServletContainerInitializer
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1271)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1180)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebappServiceLoader.loadServices(WebappServiceLoader.java:186)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebappServiceLoader.load(WebappServiceLoader.java:157)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processServletContainerInitializers(ContextConfig.java:1621)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1130)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:773)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:307)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:95)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5262)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 31 more

Jan 28, 2022 11:41:11 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/WebCSR-7.5.3.47]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:945)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:871)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1410)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1400)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/WebCSR-7.5.3.47]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:162)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/servlet/ServletContainerInitializer
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1271)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1180)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebappServiceLoader.loadServices(WebappServiceLoader.java:186)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebappServiceLoader.load(WebappServiceLoader.java:157)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.processServletContainerInitializers(ContextConfig.java:1621)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.webConfig(ContextConfig.java:1130)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:773)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:307)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:95)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5262)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.servlet.ServletContainerInitializer
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 31 more

Jan 28, 2022 11:41:11 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:192)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:945)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:441)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:789)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:641)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:349)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:483)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1410)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1400)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:871)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    ... 6 more

Jan 28, 2022 11:41:11 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
SEVERE: The required Server component failed to start so Tomcat is unable to start.
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[8002]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:641)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:349)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:483)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardService[Catalina]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:789)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    ... 7 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:162)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:441)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:145)
    ... 11 more

Jan 28, 2022 11:41:11 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8082"]
Jan 28, 2022 11:41:11 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Jan 28, 2022 11:41:11 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
INFO: Stopping service Catalina
Jan 28, 2022 11:41:11 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8082"]
Jan 28, 2022 11:41:11 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
SEVERE: Failed to destroy end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8082"]
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.releaseCaches(NioEndpoint.java:315)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.unbind(NioEndpoint.java:491)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.destroy(AbstractEndpoint.java:896)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy(AbstractProtocol.java:551)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.destroyInternal(Connector.java:1023)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.destroyInternal(StandardService.java:589)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.destroyInternal(StandardServer.java:879)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:645)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:349)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:483)

Jan 28, 2022 11:41:11 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
Jan 28, 2022 11:41:11 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
SEVERE: Failed to destroy end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.releaseCaches(NioEndpoint.java:315)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.unbind(NioEndpoint.java:491)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.destroy(AbstractEndpoint.java:896)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy(AbstractProtocol.java:551)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.destroyInternal(Connector.java:1023)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.destroyInternal(StandardService.java:589)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.destroyInternal(StandardServer.java:879)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.destroy(LifecycleBase.java:292)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:645)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:349)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:483)
```

Comment: How are you setting up these Tomcat directories? Which version of Java is being used to run them?